# How to generate checkbox for every field in database using GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have limited knowledge on VB coding. I am now creating a system which allow customer to select exhibition event and booth number they want and next reserved which day they want to rent.

By default, in GridView control can add checkbox Field but it only generate 1 checkbox for 1 row of data.

As state in the title, I have no idea how to generate the checkboxes for every field in database call D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6 and D7, each carry value 0 by default. 
Now I want every single field have a checkbox to allow customer select which day they want to reserve and retrieve their checked value to stole into corresponding D1-D7 field, checked value will update value 0 to 1.

Next, how should I coding to store the checked value into database? in default.aspx or default.aspx.vb?

Or any other suggestion to generate checkbox instead of using gridview?

The default view using GridView

[image]

What I want

[image]

My coding:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageMember.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="member_view_event_list.aspx.vb" Inherits="member_view_event_list" title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">



    <style type="text/css">
        .style8
        {
            width: 46px;
        }
        .style9
        {
        }
        .style10
        {
            width: 86px;
        }
    </style>



    </asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server" 
    contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder2">



    <table width="80%">
        <tr><td class="style10">&nbsp;</td><td class="style8">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="style10">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Event:"></asp:Label>
        </td><td class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEventList" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEvent" DataTextField="eventTitle" 
                DataValueField="eventID" AutoPostBack="True" Width="200">

            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceEvent" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [eventTitle], [eventID] FROM [booth_eventinfo]">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td><td>
                &nbsp;</td></tr>


        <tr><td class="style10">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select Booth:"></asp:Label>
            </td><td class="style8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBoothList" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceBooth" DataTextField="boothAlias" 
                DataValueField="boothID" AutoPostBack="True" Width="200">

            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceBooth" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [boothAlias], [boothID] FROM [booth_eventinfo] WHERE ([eventID] = @eventID)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEventList" Name="eventID" 
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td><td>
                 </td></tr>


        <tr><td class="style10">
            &nbsp;</td><td class="style8">
                &nbsp;</td><td>
                 &nbsp;</td></tr>


        <tr><td class="style9" colspan="3">

            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewDay" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDay" ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="D1" HeaderText="Day1" SortExpression="D1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="D2" HeaderText="Day2" SortExpression="D2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="D3" HeaderText="Day3" SortExpression="D3" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="D4" HeaderText="Day4" SortExpression="D4" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="D5" HeaderText="Day5" SortExpression="D5" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="D6" HeaderText="Day6" SortExpression="D6" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="D7" HeaderText="Day7" SortExpression="D7" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDay" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [D1], [D7], [D6], [D5], [D4], [D3], [D2] FROM [booth_eventinfo] WHERE ([boothID] = @boothID)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlBoothList" Name="boothID" 
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td></tr>


        <tr><td class="style10">
            &nbsp;</td><td class="style8">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </td><td>
                &nbsp;</td></tr>


</table>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP .NET VB - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your 'BoundField' to a 'TemplateField' for each CheckBox control you desire. The code example below shows you how to do this. Note the binding expression syntax for your DataField value:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day1" SortExpression="D1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("D1") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out. Instead of using a grid view you can use a asp:CheckBoxList, if the requirement is to only place checkboxes for the seven days. Once the list is created, you can style it horizontally using css so that it adheres to the appearance as shown in the image. This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_checkboxlist) gives a preview of a checkboxlist.

For the second part of the question, you can save it in default.aspx.vb during the final submit.

In case you want to use a gridview, then you would have to add seven templated columns and bind it to the data source.